# sdl getting continuously key pressing

Tags: c, sdl, keyevent

I am currently programming a simple game in SDL (PONG clone) where i must have a continuously key pressing.

The problem I have is that when i press a button it reacts, waits a short period and then continues to continuously key pressing.

I wonder how i get that little delay to go away.

Here is my code:

```
while (running)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        //update the game
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit_game();
            running = false;
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        { 
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)   
            {

            case SDLK_DOWN:
                move_paddle(UP);
                break;

            case SDLK_UP:
                move_paddle(DOWN);
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
        }   
    }
    draw_game();
    move_ball();
    SDL_Delay(15);
}
```

Comment: Look as though you are getting the results from auto-repeat events. `SDL_GetKeyboardState` took me about 5 seconds to google "sdl key status".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing i did was i wanted to remove the small delay and get the movement of the paddle smoother. I introduced 2 new global bool variables to keep track on which key that was pressed down.

```
bool key_up = false;
bool key_down = false;
```

I initiate them with the value false because no key is currently pressed.

In my switch I set the value for these boolean variables to match what is currently pressed down.

```
        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        { 
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)   
            {

            case SDLK_DOWN:
                key_up = true;
                key_down = false;
                break;

            case SDLK_UP:
                key_down = true;
                key_up = false;
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
        }
```

Then in the first while-loop i make two if-cases for the two keys that can be pressed and call the movement function in these if-cases.

```
    if (key_up)
        move_paddle(UP);
    else if (key_down)
        move_paddle(DOWN);
```

When i did this the delay disappeared and the paddle movement was smooth but it also generated another probelm, the paddle could not stay still in one place (except the boundraries). I then realised that the code is only looking for a key that is pressed down and does not react to a key that is released.

I then figured out that if a key is released (in this case the UP key or the DOWN key) the two boolean values had to be set to false because no key was pressed down.

What I did was that I made another if-statement after the `if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)` that would disable the movement of the paddle if no key was pressed down.

```
        if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
        {
            key_down = false;
            key_up = false;
        }
```

When I implemented all of this in my code the game worked like a charm.

For those who are interested, here is my new final code:

```
int gameloop()
{
SDL_Event event;
bool running = true;
bool key_up = false;
bool key_down = false;

while (running)
{
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        //update the game
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit_game();
            running = false;
        }

        if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
        { 
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)   
            {

            case SDLK_DOWN:
                key_up = true;
                key_down = false;
                break;

            case SDLK_UP:
                key_down = true;
                key_up = false;
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
        }

        if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP)
        {
            key_down = false;
            key_up = false;
        }
    }
    if (key_up)
        move_paddle(UP);
    else if (key_down)
        move_paddle(DOWN);

    move_ball();
    ai_paddle_move();
    draw_game();
    printf("Player: %d   |   AI: %d\n", player, ai);
    SDL_Delay(15);
}

return 1;
}
```